# owl carousel 2.2.1 add a function (like first and last item add class) but this work in one time all index

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

i have a owl carousel 2.2.1 slider i will find a function like

**owl carousal  first item  and last item add class; **

http://plnkr.co/edit/t9URfKq9Mwh9jO705h7u?p=preview

this function work in one time all index

if i will be try to make same function not working

you have any solution how it is posible

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var carousel = $(".latest-work-carousel");
carousel.owlCarousel({
    loop : true,
    items : 3,
    margin:0,
    nav : true,
    dots : false,
});

checkClasses();
carousel.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    checkClasses();
});

function checkClasses(){
    var total = $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active').length;

    $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('firstActiveItem lastActiveItem');

    $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active').each(function(index){
        if (index === 0) {
            // this is the first one
            $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem');
        }
        if (index === total - 1 && total>1) {
            // this is the last one
            $(this).addClass('lastActiveItem');
        }
    });
}
```

});

DEmo : http://plnkr.co/edit/t9URfKq9Mwh9jO705h7u?p=preview

Comment: Do you need to find the first and last element of the carousel or the first and last element within slide contents which are visible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please explain us in details?